# Como apagar arquivos antigos de uma extensão específica?

Tags: node.js

Tenho uma aplicação que cria arquivos de vídeo mp4 24/7, para fazer a limpeza destes arquivos preciso apagar todos os arquivos não modificados nos últimos 30 dias por exemplo.

Como fazer isso em Node Js? Já procurei referências e não encontrei.

Comment: Oi lys, testaste a minha resposta? Tinha um link errado que corrigi agora.

Comment: Testei sim, @Sergio. Eu vi o erro antes, mas era mínimo. A resposta foi fundamental para a solução do meu problema. Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o método [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback). Esse método disponibiliza um objeto/classe [`fs.Stats`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) que tem informação sobre a data da criação, data da ultima modificação e outras características do ficheiro.

Para usar tens de ler os ficheiros todos que tens, filtrar a extensão que queres, e correr um a um.

Um exemplo poderia ser assim:

```js
const fsReadDirRecGen = require('fs-readdir-rec-gen')
const quatroMesesAtras = (d => {
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 4);
  return d;
})(new Date());

function filtrarPorExtensao(fileName) {
  return fileName.endsWith('.mp4');
};

for (let file of fsReadDirRecGen('./test/testData', filtrarPorExtensao)) {
  const Stats = fs.statSync(file);
  if (Stats.mtime < quatroMesesAtras) {
    // apagar o ficheiro
    fs.unlinkSync(file)
  }
}
```

**Obs:** não testei, mas montei agora com a lógica que me parece ser preciso.